# Run HDFS pseudo mode in a docker container

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs, hadoop3

I'm trying to run a HDFS under pseudo mode in a docker container, configured with this page: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation, but I didn't use `start-all.sh` script as it isn't supposed to be able to do ssh, so I manually ran command `bin/hdfs --daemon start namenode|datanode` to start them one by one. The problem is I can see namenode started successfully, but datanode quited without any error message. the last piece of log from datanode is:

```
...
2018-04-09 21:04:03,830 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/apps/hadoop/hdfs/data
2018-04-09 21:04:04,188 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2018-04-09 21:04:04,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2018-04-09 21:04:04,296 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2018-04-09 21:04:04,665 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: dfs.datanode.fileio.profiling.sampling.percentage set to 0. Disabling file IO profiling
2018-04-09 21:04:04,667 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2018-04-09 21:04:04,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is hdfs
2018-04-09 21:04:04,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util: dfs.datanode.fileio.profiling.sampling.percentage set to 0. Disabling file IO profiling
2018-04-09 21:04:04,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2018-04-09 21:04:04,733 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:9866
2018-04-09 21:04:04,735 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwidth is 10485760 bytes/s
2018-04-09 21:04:04,735 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 50
```

`core-site.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

And `hdfs-site.xml` is

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/apps/hadoop/hdfs/name</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/apps/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Did I miss any thing from there?

Comment: add port -> hdfs://localhost:9000

Comment: Plenty of Hadoop images already exist... Look at Sequenceiq or BDEurope https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop

Answer (score 1):

I think it is base image issue, I was using alpine, once I changed to centos, datanode works! must be something missing from alpine, appreciate if anyone knows what is it, as centos based image eventually will much more bigger then alpine.

Comment: I had the same problem a couple of days. The datanode nodes created a core, not sure why. I switched to openjdk docker base image and the same setup now works fine.